# $parse:syntax error while using {{variable}} in ui select repeat

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am getting angular.js:13920Error: [$parse:syntax] when i am using {{variable_name}} with string within repeat of ui-select-choices.

```
<ui-select ng-model="dfaDetail.location.selected" theme="bootstrap" style="width:300px;">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search Location...">{{$select.selected.locationCode}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="item in locData{{myindex}} | filter: $select.search">
              <div ng-bind-html="item.locationCode | highlight: $select.search"></div>
              <small ng-bind-html="item.locationId | highlight: $select.search"></small>
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

I am already using string concatenation with variable similar to above select ng-options repeat as below, however for able i am getting error.

```
<select data-live-search="true" data-size="15" data-container="body" title="Location Name:" name="choose_loc" ng-model = "dfaDetails.locationName" 
                                        ng-options="p.locationId as p.locationCode for p in locData{{myno}}">
                                        <option class="small-font" value="">Select Location </option>
                                        </select>
```

Is there any way i can use dynamic variable with repeat. 
Usecase: for each row i would have new variable like locData1, locData2.. so i want to use locData{{myno}} where myno is having incremental number.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `{{}}` interpolation directive inside ng-repeat`. Basically you wanted to access object via its key, so you could do it like this`locData[myindex]`

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in locData[myindex] | filter: $select.search">
```

In `ng-options`

```
ng-options="p.locationId as p.locationCode for p in locData[myno]"
```

Comment: when I am trying in plunker it allows to use {{}} within ui select choices repeat.. however within my application it errors with parsing syntax

Comment: Where is the plunkr? can you please update plunkr with the same?

Comment: Issue is with latest version of ui-select.
Plunker - http://embed.plnkr.co/jBJkDb